# Meaning of "tasting only what was to come."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> I thought the four-week voyage would never end. So eager was I to reach
>   Africa that at times the ship seemed caught in the water like a leaf endlessly
>   turning around in a pool. I ate my chocolates, read my books, dined, and
>   chatted with the other passengers, but my mind was always sailing ahead of
>   the ship. Would I be able to rebuild Tumaini? Would the lives of the Kikuyu
>   and Masai be safe in my hands? Would the Kikuyu and Masai trust me? One
>   day I answered the questions one way and the next day another way. **I was
>   like the leopard at the moment before it springs, tasting only what was to
>   come.**

Dose The whole sentence in bold mean: I was like a leopard that still has not jumped to his prey and did not know what his prey is and at last taste something that he hunt??

Source: 
Listening for Lions by
Gloria Whelan

Comment: She imagines the leopard, about to pounce on its prey, being able to taste the meal in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The leopard, waiting to pounce, is thinking only of what the meat will taste like and not paying attention at all to what is going on around it.